# "Total" and "Subtotal" text is not showing on Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, styles

Hi I have one small issue on [Woocommerce checkout](https://huskypalace.com/product/siberian-husky-adoption-deposit/). For some reason checkout styles was messed up, and now Total and subtotal are not shown..

This is how looks on my site:

[image]

and this is how should look :

[image]

I tryed to insert this css:

```
.checkout .shop_table tfoot {
border-top: 1px solid;
border-bottom: 1px solid;
margin-left: -600px;
}
```

but that not changed nothing.. Im confused. Any tip how to resolve this mess?

Comment: Working with woocommerce css always seems cumbersome. Maybe just put display: block on shop-table and take it from there.

Comment: Still dont show me price on total and subtotal? How to fix that?

Comment: Fixed myself by this: `.checkout .shop_table tfoot tr {display:table;`